# Question involving ratios and Greatest Common Divisors

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, ratio

Consider 6 variables $a,b,c,x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$. We have two ratios, $a:b:c=1:2:3$ and $x:y:z=1:2:3$. We also have that $\gcd(a,x)=2$. What is $\gcd(a+b+c,x+y+z)$? I know that $\gcd(a,x)=2$, which means $a$ and $x$ are even, but I'm not too sure how to use this information to solve the problem. I also tried to use the ratios in some way, but I couldn't get far. I noted that $y=2x$, $z=3x$. $b=2a$, and $c=3a$, so $\gcd(a+b+c,x+y+z)=\gcd(a+2a+3a,x+2x+3x)=\gcd(6a,6x)$, but I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Could someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Use $\frac ba =2$ and $\frac ca =3$ and $\frac yx = 2$ and $\frac zx =3$ to figure out what $a+b +c$ is in terms of $a$ and what $x+y+z$ is in terms of $x$.  Then I'll undelete my answer.

Comment: See my edit. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Use $\gcd(jm,jn) = j\gcd(m,n)$ (But you must prove that if you've never used it before)

Comment: Oh thanks. I've never seen that rule before. I think I can solve the problem now.

Comment: Then you'd best prove it.  It's clear that if $\gcd(m,n)=d$ then $d|m$ and $d|n$ so $jd|jm$ and $jd|jn$. So $\gcd(jm,jn) \ge j\gcd(m,n)$ and that $jd|\gcd(jm,jn)$ but you must prove it is the *greatest* common denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's roll out the tanks.

$b = 2a; c=3a; y=2x;z=3x$.

So $a+b + c =6a$ and $x+y+z=6x$.

So you are asked to find the $\gcd(6a,6x)$ give that $\gcd(a,x)=2$.

Can you take it from there?

> Use $\gcd(jm,jn) = j\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: So $\gcd(6a,6x)=6\gcd(a,x)=6\cdot2=12$, right?